# Dynamic search bar in jQuery with result display problems

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small question: I created a dynamic search bar until now it's ok. But the problem I have is that when I type the beginning of a letter or a number, I don't have a display limit it takes all the page someone already have a solution?

Thanks a lot

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-stock').keyup(function (){
        $('#result-search').html('');
        var stock = $(this).val();
        if (stock != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../ajax/stock_search.php',
                data: 'stocks=' + encodeURIComponent(stock),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "")
                    {

                        $('#result-search').append(data);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('result-search').innerHTML = "" + "<div style='font-size: 20px; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px'> Aucun élement trouver</div>"
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../include/bdd.php');


if(isset($_GET['stocks'])){

    $stock_aema = (string) trim($_GET['stocks']);
    $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock_aema WHERE model LIKE :model LIMIT 10");
    $req2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock_aema WHERE id LIKE :id LIMIT 10");
    $req3 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock_aema WHERE aema LIKE :aema LIMIT 10");

    $req->execute(array('model' => "%$stock_aema%"));
    $req = $req->fetchAll();

    foreach ($req as $r){
        ?>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px ; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc">
            <?= $r['id'] . " " . $r['model']. " " . $r['aema']?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    $req2->execute(array('id' => "%$stock_aema%"));
    $req2 = $req2->fetchAll();

    foreach ($req2 as $s){
        ?>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px ; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc">
            <?= $s['id'] . " " . $s['model']. " " . $s['aema']?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    $req3->execute(array('aema' => strval("%$stock_aema%")));
    $req3 = $req3->fetchAll();

    foreach ($req3 as $x){
        ?>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px ; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc">
            <?= $x['id'] . " " . $x['model']. " " . $x['aema']?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It might be a good practice to not fire off a search request until there are at least 3 characters...? Also, consider using pagination

Comment: Also, small thing, consider keeping your code aligned to the framework you've chosen to use `document.getElementById('result-search').innerHTML`  => `$("#result-search").html(`

Comment: And why do you have 3 different queries? Just make it one with `OR`